# Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library_Assertion Failed/GUI using MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

While running a GUI developed by C++, I receive the following error when I want to open a file by that application;

Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library Program: C:\Windows\SYSYTEM32\mfc140d.dll Debug Assertion Failed! File: d:\agent_work\9\s\src\vctools\VC7Libs\Ship\ATLMFC\Src\MFC\filelist. Line:221 For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts. (Press Retry to debug the application) 1)Abort 2)Retry 3)Ignore

It gives that error for the following command:

```
if (!pFile->Open (szFOutName, CFile::modeRead, &FEx))



{

    //......The file can't be opened. Alert the user.

    if (szFOutName != "")

        AfxMessageBox ("Output doesn't exist, please run the simulation first!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK, 0);

   

    //......Get rid of the file handle, and reset szFileName.                                            

    delete pFile;

   

    szFOutName   = "";

    nopen=2;

}
```

The error is at the first line (if). Does anyone know what is the reason? I am a beginner and the codes are developed by a senior colleague in the company I work.
Thanks in advance, Sanaz

Comment: What is `pFile`? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ***Does anyone know what is the reason?*** Looking at the line of code that asserts in the MFC sources should tell you what parameter in this call `pFile->Open (szFOutName, CFile::modeRead, &FEx)` is bad.

Comment: Has something changed since Oct. 28: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64612525/microsoft-visual-c-runtime-library-assertion-failed ?

Comment: Yes, I found where the error is. @VladFeinstein

Answer (score 1):

Here is the MFC code (line 221 is marked with my comment):

```
void CRecentFileList::Add(LPCTSTR lpszPathName, LPCTSTR lpszAppID)
{
    CWinApp* pApp = AfxGetApp();
    if (pApp == NULL || !pApp->IsWindows7())
    {
        Add(lpszPathName);
        return;
    }

    CString strAppID = lpszAppID == NULL ? _T("") : lpszAppID;

    ASSERT(AfxIsValidString(lpszPathName));

    Add(lpszPathName);

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    CComPtr<IShellItem> psi = NULL;

#ifdef UNICODE
    hr = _AfxSHCreateItemFromParsingName(lpszPathName, NULL, IID_IShellItem, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&psi));
#else
    {
        USES_CONVERSION;
        LPOLESTR lpWPath = A2W(lpszPathName);
        hr = _AfxSHCreateItemFromParsingName(lpWPath, NULL, IID_IShellItem, (LPVOID*)&psi);
    }
#endif

    ENSURE(SUCCEEDED(hr)); // THIS IS LINE 221

    Add(psi, strAppID);
}
```

I have two guesses:

1. You messed up the UNICODE setting for the project
2. COM in not initialized